# What is to be considered as "dose" in money matters? (about zodical sign Pisces)

Tags: word-meaning

The extract in italics given below:

These qualities make them, however, much misunderstood, and *they are often considered dose in money matters* when in reality they are not.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a typographical/OCR error.

Answer (score 7):

*dose* appears to be a misreading or mis-scan of *close* ; the sentence  appears with that term in *The Cheiro Book of Fate and Fortune*:

[image]

I have been unable to pin down the date this was first published. 'Cheiro' was the occultist William John Warner (1866-1936), who also called himself 'Count Louis Hamon'.

*Close* in this context means *ungenerous, tight-fisted*.

Comment: Wonderful pinning of the source! It seems that in astrology, the exact meaning of words is not as important as in other fields... so misquotes (or bad copying) can proliferate.

Comment: Brilliant! You are my hero, StoneyB! +1 as usual.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence has been travelling from site to site with the same wording. For example, you can read it [here](http://www.gotohoroscope.com/pisces-meanings.html), and [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091201084605AAW0fsM), and [here](http://melmosmermaidparadise.com/MermaidTales.html), and on quite a few other sites.

So it's hardly believable that the word "dose", used in this sentence as an adjective was a mere misspelling - otherwise it would've been spotted by the natives.

My search has led me to the [site of Irish slang](http://www.slang.ie/index.php?county=all&entry=dose&letter=D) where the word "dose" defined as something bad, annoying or disappointing. Could it be there that "dose" in the sentence from the horoscope came from?

Comment: Good find! +1 OTOH, never underestimate the "dose" of the general public, no matter how often it appears on the web. :-)